# How to set and get dates in google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

In javascript we generally do
`var date = new Date()` and if we want to increase and compare later 
var `newDate = date.setSeconds(1000)` now we can compare **date < newDate** or not

I am writing a gmail addon in that i need use similar kind of thing. How can do this in google script.

I tried to find it in the google script documentation but i am not able to find this. 
Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script. The first paragraph say "All on a JavaScript platform in the cloud." If you already tried to use new Date() and do the mentioned comparison add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps Script still uses the JavaScript `new Date()` definition for dates, though when you  use `date.setSeconds(1000)` the date gets converted to Unix time. Google uses Unix time in milliseconds.

Calling `date.setSeconds()` **changes the variable date even when calling it inside** `newDate = date.setSeconds(1000)`.

You can fix this by with:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var date = new Date()
  var newDate = new Date(unixTimeConverter(date).setSeconds(1000));
}

function unixTimeConverter(n) {
  return new Date(n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. it was working. but if i compare date and newDate always getting false. How can compare these two here?

Comment: How are you comparing them? If you log the comparison from your original question using `Logger.log(date < newDate);` it should return true: https://imgur.com/TvW2Pez

Comment: ```
function myFunction() {
    var eventDetails = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    var curr_date = new Date();
    var newDate = new Date(unixTimeConverter(curr_date).setSeconds(36640));
    eventDetails.setProperty("timeStamp", newDate);
    var timeStamp = eventDetails.getProperty("timeStamp");
    Logger.log(curr_date < timeStamp);
}
```
i am getting false for this

Comment: The [`getProperty()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties.html#getpropertykey) returns a string and so the comparison of types `object < string` will return false. You can fix with `curr_date < new Date(timeStamp)`.